# Dynamically rendering ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want a component to be re-rendered with different attributes on chaninging a controller property. So, I have my code like,

```
{{#if (eq diffView "type1")}}
   {{comp/mycomp diffId=diffFile.id  diffIdPrefix=diffView view=diffView thisCtrl=thisCtrl commitDiff=diffFile.diff filePath=diffFile.fileName}}
{{else}}
   {{comp/mycomp diffId=diffFile.id  diffIdPrefix=diffView view="line-by-line" thisCtrl=thisCtrl commitDiff=diffFile.diff filePath=diffFile.fileName}}
{{/if}}
```

Changing the property diffView, throws me error like,

> vendorrepository.js:13602 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute
>   ‘removeChild’ on ‘Node’: The node to be removed is not a child of this
>   node. at clear(…) at UpdatableBlockTracker.reset (…) at
>   TryOpcode.handleException (…)

This error was inside ember source code. I think there was some error trying to remove the older component. Pls help me out with this issue.

Comment: It looks your code is perfect. There is a chance for the source of the issue in some other place.

Comment: I think there is error is destroying the older component.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following :

```
{{comp/mycomp
    diffId=diffFile.id
    diffIdPrefix=diffView
    view=(if (eq diffView "type1") diffView "line-by-line")
    thisCtrl=thisCtrl
    commitDiff=diffFile.diff
    filePath=diffFile.fileName
}}
```

the idea is to put the `if` only on the changing attribute

Comment: Yeah I had it like
``
{{comp/mycomp diffId=diffFile.id  diffIdPrefix=diffView view=diffView thisCtrl=thisCtrl commitDiff=diffFile.diff filePath=diffFile.fileName}}
``
Because the same component is going to be rendered again with a different value in 'diffView'

The problem is 'diffView' value during component render only will be passed to the component and value change will not be reflected in the component. So I had to have a condition in template and re-render the component on change.